# Git commit / push through Teamcity

Tags: git, teamcity

I have a project in teamcity that has the following structure. The developers develop against some git repository. They push their changes and the teamcity CI build does its job. I would like to chain a Release build to it to publish changes to a Github repository once everyone agrees.

I understand how I could do this through a command line script but I was wondering if I could declare a VCC (that won't be used for pulling) and somehow push to it? Otherwise I have unencrypted passwords on my cmd script, which I would like to avoid.

Thanks
Yannis

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using github to store binaries/output from a build?  I'd recommend something like Artifactory which works well with TeamCity.  If you must use git, you'll probably have to manually enter a script into steps (e.g.: git add ., git push, etc.).