# How to merge and commit to a branch in TeamCity

Tags: asp.net, git, deployment, teamcity, springloops

I want to figure out how to integrate TeamCity builds with Springloops deployments.

Lets say I have a Git repo called `api` that has two branches `dev` and `dev.build`

```
api
|-- dev
|-- dev.build
```

I have set up TeamCity with a VCS trigger on `dev` to build upon commit. Which then creates artifacts that I want to use to deploy. (In this case it's an ASP.NET website with various DLLs that I want to use for deployment).

I also have Springloops that I use right now for deployments. Ideally I would like to deploy from `dev.build`. Is there a way to commit build artifacts from TeamCity to the `dev.build` branch, and then deploy from that branch?

The basic workflow would be

1. Commit code to `dev`
2. TeamCity merges `dev` into `dev.build`
3. TeamCity builds from `dev.build`
4. TeamCity commits artifacts (DLLs) to `dev.build`
5. Springloops auto deploys from `dev.build`

I have [read arguments against storing build binaries/artifacts in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738892/git-commit-push-through-teamcity), but right now I do my deployments from Springloops, and ideally I could keep that setup. I know you can [call `git` as a command line build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326487/teamcity-on-successful-build-push-to-git-repo), but I'm having trouble putting all the pieces together. Especially how to merge from `dev` to `dev.build` as a TeamCity build step and then use `dev.build` to build from.

Is this possible at all? Am I thinking about this completely wrong? Do I have other options?

**Edit/Update**

I've found that it will be smarter to switch to using WebDeploy to deploy TeamCity artifacts (WebDeploy package) instead of committing build artifacts from a git repository via Springloops. I will hopefully stop using Springloops for deployments and deploy directly to my IIS sites via WebDeploy through a TeamCity build task. This way build artifacts (`\bin` folder) will stay out of git, and `web.config` transforms can also be used instead of manually making `web.config` edits on production IIS sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other option I would recommend is to [build a TeamCity **Artifact**](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Artifact), which is there to store the result of your job in an integrated lightweight builds artifact repository.

That way, [Springloops](http://www.springloops.io/) could look for artifacts to deploy directly on a TeamCity url (or on a TeamCity agent).
That would scale better than trying to put those artifacts in a *source* code repo like Git, which isn't made for that.

Regarding the TeamCity build itself, it could be compose of two jobs (one dependent on the other) with the first one using the [automatic merge feature](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/10/automatic-merge/), in order to merge `dev` to `dev.build`.

Comment: I think with combining automatic merge and a git commit step I can make it happen. I don't think a TeamCity Artifact would work because when deploying, I need to deploy the whole git repository including the build artifacts.

Comment: While this answer is valid for my original question, it is definitely not considered "best practice" to deploy build artifacts from a git repository. I realized I was really asking the wrong question. See my edit for WebDeploy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this is totally doable in TeamCity. In fact Jetbrains covers a lot of this in a blog post [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/10/automatic-merge/).